# How to load images to js file in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I would like to display photos using this photo grid program.

https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Currently I use Laravel and I can display photo useing below code

**Blade**

```
@if($images->count())
    @foreach($images as $image)
        <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="images/{{ $image->image }}" title="{{ $image->title }}">                     
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="images/{{ $image->image }}" />
        </a>         
        </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getRandomSize(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  var height =  getRandomSize(200, 400);
  $('#photos').append('<img src="images/{{ $image->image }}'+width+'/'+height+'/cats" alt="">');
}

</script>
```

Photos are won't show up. Could you teach me how to write right code please?

Comment: What does `$image->image` return?

Comment: Dear @Dragonsnap  Thank you for answering me and edit. $image->image is filename. and JPG file are stored in public/images. Am I answering correctly?

Comment: View the source in your browser and take a look at the URL path to the image. If you can't click on it and show the image, the path is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the images are stored in directories inside `storage/app/public`, and that you have linked the `storage` folder by running

```sh
php artisan storage:link
```

Then, whenever you're fetching from the `storage/app/public` folder, use

```php
{{asset('/directory/from/public/to/your/file')}}
```

So if you have an image stored as `storage/app/public/images/foo.jpg`, use something like this:

```php
<img src = "{{asset('images/foo.jpg')}}"
```

I belive that's the best pratice for storing external resources for Laravel projects.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. May I have time to understand this. As soon as I can display photo I will contact you.

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked! I really apreciate.